# Implicit intents not working with Android Lyft app

Tags: android, lyft-api

Our app is using implicit intents to open a map view with a given geo location. For example, we create an implicit intent with a data URI of

`geo:0,0?q=45.160410,-93.227063`

as explained in https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-common#ViewMap. However, when this is opened in Lyft the app gives an error "Unsupported Address" as shown in the attached screengrab.

The same intent works in Google Maps, Uber and Waze. Should it work in Lyft?

[Lyft address error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A3J53.png)

Comment: The official `lyft-api` documentation tells you how to deeplink: https://developer.lyft.com/docs/deeplinking - Maybe you can use that to open the Lyft app. I'm not sure about how to open it in a specific place.

Comment: @nbokmans Thanks! I saw that too, but I think that requires building your own UI for app selection. We're using the system's Intent.createChooser, which works with any app on the device but doesn't tell us if the Lyft app was chosen. We looked at using the intent picker but that looks old and outdated.

I'm a little surprised the Lyft app reports to the system it supports geo: intents but can't actually parse them.